# Directory organisation in GIT

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am newbie to GIT having switched from SVN recently, i am facing issue on what would be the good way to organise all of my project files in GIT.

My projects generally consist of four type of data, namely.

1. App (contains files related to web application)
2. Design (contains PSD file provided by designer)
3. Template (contains HTML/CSS files provided by front end developer)
4. Document (contains files related to documentation of the project and provided by client)

In SVN i used to create the above mentioned four directories in root and would ask the respective team member to checkout specific directory as what is needed to them.

For example

- UI designer needs access to 'Design' directory only.
- Frontend team needs access to 'Template and Design' directory only.
- Backend programmer needs access to 'Template and App' directory only.
- Administrator needs access to all the directories.

In SVN it was pretty easy to achieve this as i would just checkout the desired directory and keep committing the same for the changes to take effect, but it is different in GIT as i got to learn that it is not possible for me to clone one specific directory within the repository.

I would want to follow the same practice with GIT and want the team to give access to resources which is needed to them and not necessarily all.

As GIT will not allow me to clone one specific directory, i was thinking may be creating different branches and storing accordingly can be good idea. Or i can make a fork for each individual type of data ?

I am not bothered about the permissions wether who access what, it is okay for me if the designer get access to App or Document directory, the only point is i don't want everyone to clone the whole repository since it is meaningless for every team member to download everything which they do not require. and any how it will also add up to the download/upload time since on an average the design directory alone consist of approximately 300-400 mb.

Please throw some light on what will be the good way to handle such situation ?

P.S: I am using [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) for repository

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your information, I would suggest one of two choices:

1. Have each of the 4 different "concentration areas" in their own repository or
2. Have each of your concentration areas in a branch, all in the same repository.

I favor the first, because it would be easier to handle. Just create repository names like "project-app", "project-design" etc.

If you choose to have one branch per group, you will need to set remote tracking branches for each of the branches.

With their individual repositories you will only need to worry about remote tracking branches if someone starts a long-term development on one of the branches and need others to collaborate.

You can even replicate SVN's organization (I do find this helpful), creating a / dir on each of the clients and then only checking out the repositories you need with their "base" name, like

```
mkdir my_project
cd my_project
git clone https://me@bitbucket.org/me/my_project-app.git app
git clone https://me@bitbucket.org/me/my_project-design.git design
```

and so on... So your dir structure will be just as the one your had in SVN, with /my_project/app, /my_project/design etc.

So you will have individual local repositories for each of your focus areas.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible directly with git, however, there are 2 options:

- Use a separate branch for each component
- Create a separate repository for each component.

I recommend creating a separate repository as branching would undermine the actual branching.  For example, if you wanted to branch each component for a "MYSITE_V2", you'd end up creating a branch of each branch.  Could get messy.

A third option is to accept this limitation.  If your developers only need to clone the repo once and then they push/pull changes, the bandwidth concern is mitigated.  Just train them to understand that their work is in a sub-directory of the repo.  They will understand.

Comment: I thought of creating separate repository for each one, but again that would end up having many repositories since I usually create new project every 15 days. And quickly it will be lot of repositories.